# Showing image from server issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, blob

I am using awesome.cropper.js as plugin for cropping picture for profile picture upload and then sending the picture in server. When I download the image from server the image is ok. But when I go to the url, then the image become distorted. Look at the image url.
[image from server](http://54.186.75.239:9000/Image/public/images/dispatcher_images/2016-07-20T13:49:58.551Zblob)

```
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    var result=$("#setPicture2").attr('value');
    var blobBin = atob(result.split(',')[1]);
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < blobBin.length; i++) {
        array.push(blobBin.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    var file=new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/png'});
    console.log(file);
    formData.append("picture", file);     
    accountInfo.savePropic(formData);
```

I am using blob to send image. But when I use the url from server for showing, the image lost it's color. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is the original image MIME type `image/png`? Are you trying to convert from `data URI` to `Blob`?

Comment: Try `var mimeString = result.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];` and in the `Blob` constructor, pass `{type: mimeString}`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts There should not be a `:` or `;` character following `,` at `data URI`? That is, if `result` is a valid `data URI`

Comment: @AmitBiswas Can you include text of `result` at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 I got that line from an older version of https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/blob/master/js/canvas-to-blob.js

Comment: @guest271314 [here's the line I got it from](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/blob/b107a012d06bc4cb1ae93f4e1e9c64653814d6c4/js/canvas-to-blob.js#L61)

Comment: @AmitBiswas Unclear what `result` is?

Comment: $cropSandbox = $('<canvas></canvas>');      
var result;
result = $cropSandbox.get(0).toDataURL();
$("#setPicture").attr('src', result);

Comment: At last I found that this is not front end problem. This happened for backend implementation while converting the image to byte array. Thanks all :)